# Solidity: Can’t set the allowance to use transferFrom

Tags: solidity, erc20, openzeppelin

here's my method to allow the user to sell "FRKC" ERC20 tokens to get ETH in return from my smart contract

When I log the allowance variable it stays at 0

On Remix I get the error: **"Check the token allowance."**

I made sure my user had enough tokens to sell and my contract has enough ETH to send
Am I supposed to call the approve function somewhere? Couldn't find a good example

```
function sell(uint256 amount) public {
        // Allowance
        uint256 allowance = FrkcReserve.allowance(msg.sender, address(this));
        require(allowance >= amount, "Check the token allowance.");

        // Get tokens from the user
        bool sent = FrkcReserve.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), amount);
        require(sent, "Failed to transfer tokens from user to vendor");

        // Sent ETH to the user
        (sent, ) = msg.sender.call{value: amountOfETHToTransfer}("");
        require(sent, "Failed to send ETH to the user");

        emit Sold(amount);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

> *Am I supposed to call the approve function somewhere?*

Yes. The user needs to execute the `approve()` function **directly from their address** (not through your contract). Specifically, they need to pass **your contract** address as the first param, and the **amount** as the second param.

The approved amount is then reflected in the value returned from `allowance()`.

This is a common practice used by majority of DEXes. For example when you're selling an XYZ token on Uniswap, you need to `approve()` them first to pull the token from your wallet.